# Azure Manage IIS Web 'x' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am Deploying My website and in the task WinRM I am getting the error "##[error]Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: Deployment on one or more machines failed. System.Exception: 'x' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."

What is "X"?

```
2019-06-10T18:29:43.2417805Z ##[section]Starting: Manage IIS App:xxWeb
2019-06-10T18:29:43.2417805Z ==============================================================================
2019-06-10T18:29:43.2417805Z Task         : WinRM - IIS Web App Management
2019-06-10T18:29:43.2417805Z Description  : Connect via WinRM, to create or update the Website and App Pool locally on IIS
2019-06-10T18:29:43.2417805Z Version      : 1.3.4
2019-06-10T18:29:43.2417805Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-06-10T18:29:43.2417805Z Help         : [More Information](http://aka.ms/IISMgmt)
2019-06-10T18:29:43.2417805Z ==============================================================================
2019-06-10T18:29:43.2574066Z Preparing task execution handler.
2019-06-10T18:29:43.7574097Z Executing the powershell script: D:\TFSVSOWork\_tasks\IISWebAppMgmt_0f5cd14f-3c01-4d5c-8f7a-eb96c5738dcc\1.3.4\Main.ps1
2019-06-10T18:29:44.0230429Z Started creating website: zzWeb
2019-06-10T18:29:44.0230429Z 
2019-06-10T18:29:44.0230429Z 
2019-06-10T18:29:44.1167998Z Performing deployment in parallel on all the machines.
2019-06-10T18:29:44.1167998Z 
2019-06-10T18:29:44.1167998Z 
2019-06-10T18:29:44.1324152Z Deployment started for machine: ABC with port 5985.
2019-06-10T18:29:44.1324152Z 
2019-06-10T18:29:44.1324152Z 
2019-06-10T18:29:55.3845707Z Deployment status for machine ABC : Failed
2019-06-10T18:29:55.3845707Z 
2019-06-10T18:29:55.3845707Z 
2019-06-10T18:29:55.3845707Z Deployment failed on machine ABC with following message : System.Exception: 'x' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
2019-06-10T18:29:55.3845707Z SITE object "zzWeb" changed
2019-06-10T18:29:55.3845707Z 
2019-06-10T18:29:55.3845707Z 
2019-06-10T18:29:55.4001931Z 
2019-06-10T18:29:55.4158230Z 
2019-06-10T18:29:55.4158230Z ##[error]Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: Deployment on one or more machines failed. System.Exception: 'x' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
2019-06-10T18:29:55.4158230Z SITE object "zzWeb" changed
2019-06-10T18:29:55.4158230Z For more info please refer to http://aka.ms/iisextnreadme
2019-06-10T18:29:55.4470744Z ##[error]PowerShell script completed with 1 errors.
2019-06-10T18:29:55.4470744Z ##[section]Finishing: Manage IIS App:zzWeb
```

I went poking around with the Event Viewer, but not seeing anything in logs close to this time.  I have this working on DEV and Test servers, I'm sure some one for got to set something up on these new servers, But I cant tell what it is.

Comment: This does work $soptions = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck 
$cred = Get-Credential 
$computername = 'vvvvvvvvv' 
$computerport = '5985' 
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $computername -Port $computerport -Credential $cred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesterday after using Debug mode, we came to the conclusion we had a bad Password.  Appcmd.exe doesn't handle a '&' in a password.  Which caused the next letter to be a command, in our case x.  I hope this might help others that hit this.